# Sending json data in reverse order to a website through python

Tags: python, json, python-asyncio

So I've been working on a small project as a learning experience from a concept that started out as just a joke between friends.

The idea is that python will process data in reverse order from a .json file then send each 1000 characters as comments to a website that has a 1000 character limit.

Currently it's working as intended however when printed the comments appear out of order with repetition. So what would be

> ```
> This is a test print
> if this displays correctly
> then the everything is
> working as intended
> ```

Would display as

> ```
> then everything is
> working as intended
> if this displays correctly
> if this displays correctly
> This is a test print
> ```

I've isolated what I believe could be the issue, but do not understand why the issue is occurring. Any feedback would be great, thanks in advance.

Possible issue 1:

```
script_path = 'script.json'
with open(script_path, 'r') as f:
  script = json.loads(f.read())

def reverse(l):
  size = len(l)
  nindex = size - 1
  ll = int(size/2)
  for i in range(0, ll):
    temp = l[nindex]
    l[nindex] = l[i] 
    l[i] = temp
    nindex -= 1

i = 0
count = 0
script_small_parts = []
script_parts = {}
for x in script:
  if i > 10:
    i = 0
    script_parts.update({count:script_small_parts})
    count += 1
    script_small_parts = []
    script_small_parts.append(x)
  script_small_parts.append(x)
  i += 1
  if count == 179:
    script_parts.update({count:script_small_parts})
```

Possible issue 2:

```
async def main():
  message = ''
  count = 0
  reverse(script_parts)
  for x in script_parts:
    for s in script_parts[x]:
      if len(s) < 1000 and len(message) < 800:
        message += s
      else:
        payload = {'comment': message, 'count': '6', 'sessionid': session_id}
        try:
          r = requests.post(api, headers=headers, cookies=cookies, data=payload)
          if r.json()['success'] == 'false':
            print("Something has gone wrong.")
            return
        except Exception as e:
          print("Something has gone wrong.")
          return
        message = ''
        message += str(s)
        count += 1
        print('Comment {0}/{1} Sent\nDelay: {2} seconds'.format(count, len(script_parts), delay))
        await asyncio.sleep(delay)
  last_comment = 'The test is now over'
  payload = {'comment': last_comment, 'count': '6', 'sessionid': session_id}
  r = requests.post(api, headers=headers, cookies=cookies, data=payload)
  print("done")
```